# How to open webView with a data (html page) I got as response from get/post request?

Tags: html, objective-c, webview

I send get/post http request and as response I receive string with html source code of a page.

How do I load or display this page into webView?

e.g. response example (now there is an error, but will be a correct page):

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as below

```
NSString *html = your html content here;  
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

If you don't have html tag in your text then change it to below

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>", your html content here];
```

Comment: oh, great, thank you. I thought It'd be simple, but did't know hot to do it )